# Configuring property map<String , map<string,string>> in spring junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-webflux

I have a client class that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "someproperties")
public class SomeClient {

    private final WebClient webclient;

    public  Map<String, Map<String, String>> urlmap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

  
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<SomeResponse>> getSomeData(String resourceId, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        String uri = null;
        
        List<String> env = some-keys..;

        if(!Objects.isNull(env))
        {
            uri = urlmap.get(env.get(0)).get("url1");
        }
        else
        {
            uri = urlmap.get("prod").get("url2");
        }
        


       //and call the target sevice

    }
```

My properties look like this:

```
someproperties:
  urlmap:
    dev:
      url1 : http://something1.com
      url2 : http://something2.com 
    qa:
      url1 : http://something1.com
      url2 : http://something2.com
```

When i run the app it works fine, but my junit fails with null pointer exception at:
It seems like the urlmap was not initialized

```
 else
        {
            uri = urlmap.get("prod").get("url2");
        }
```

In order to get it working with the junits, i added annotations:
My junit looks like:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = SomeClient.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "someproperties")
public class SomeClientTest {

    private static final String SOME_URL = "/v2/something/{someid}/resource";

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeClient someClient;

    @Mock
    private CustomWebClient genericWebClient;
    
    @Mock
    private Map<String, Map<String,String>> urlMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

    @Test
    public void testGetSomething() throws IOException {
\
        Map<String, Map<String,String>> uriMap = generateUriMap();


        String someID = "jhfjhtf6";
        Map<String,String> pathVars = new HashedMap<>();
        pathVars.put("someId",someID);


        when(genericWebClient.invoketarget(any(URI.class),any(), any(Class.class), any(HttpMethod.class),any(Some.class), // invoketarget is a custome method
                anyBoolean(), any(Smething.class))).thenReturn(somemonoresponse);
        when(someUtil.typeCastToMonoResponseEntity(any())).thenReturn(somemonoresponse);
 

        Mono<ResponseEntity<somemonoresponse>> resp = someClient.getSomething(someID,webExchange);

        StepVerifier.create(consumerIdInsights)
                .consumeNextWith(response -> {
                    assertNotNull(response);
                })
                .verifyComplete();
    }
```

How should i mock/autowire/initialize this map ???

Answer (score 0):

The following is a minimal example.

In src/test/resources create application.yml containing the following:

```
someproperties:
  urlmap:
    dev:
      url1 : http://something1.com
      url2 : http://something2.com 
    qa:
      url1 : http://something1.com
      url2 : http://something2.com
```

Create a wrapper class for `someproperties`. I didn't use Lombok @Data for clarity:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="someproperties")
public class SomeProperties {

    public Map<String, Map<String,String>> urlmap;

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getUrlmap() {
        return urlmap;
    }

    public void setUrlmap(Map<String, Map<String, String>> urlmap) {
        this.urlmap = urlmap;
    }


}
```

Reference `SomeProperties` from your `ConsumersClient` class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ConsumersClient {

    @Autowired
    SomeProperties someProperties;
    
    public void demo() {
        String uri = null;
        

            uri = someProperties.getUrlmap().get("dev").get("url1");
            
            System.out.println("dev/url1: " + uri);

            uri = someProperties.getUrlmap().get("prod").get("url2");
 
            System.out.println("prod/url2: " + uri);
    }

}
```

Create a JUnit5 test as follows:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.yml")
public class SomeClientTest {

    @Autowired
    ConsumersClient consumersClient;

    @Test
    public void testGetSomething() throws IOException {
        consumersClient.demo();
    }
}
```

Run it

[image: test results]